# API будет вызываться из других частей JavaScript-кода...

Tags: api, веб-сервер, javascript

Я новичок, поэтому прошу не ругать, если вопрос глупый-глупый. Что значит, когда говорят: "API будет вызываться из других частей JavaScript-кода без необходимости дополнительных запросов между браузером и сервером"?
Значит, что не стоит создавать формочек, дополнительных диалоговых окон и т.д.?

Answer (score 1):

Что помешало указать о каком API конкретно речь? Относительно вопроса думаю это значит, что API сам умеет когда надо отправлять запросы и получать ответы(дополнительных не надо).